# AWS SQS messages does not become available again after visibility timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

This is most likely something really simple but for some reason my SQS messages does not become available again after visibility timeout. At least this is what I figured since consuming lambda has no log entries indicating that any retries have been triggered.

My use case is that another lambda is feeding SQS queue with JSON entities that then needs to be sent forward. Sometimes there's so much data to be sent that receiving end is responding with HTTP 429.

My sending lambda (JSON body over HTTPS) is deleting the messages from queue only when service is responding with HTTP 200, otherwise I do nothing with the `receiptHandle` which I think should then keep the message in the queue.

Anyway, when request is rejected by the service, the message does not become available anymore and so it's never tried to send again and is forever lost.

Incoming SQS has been setup as follows:

- Visibility timeout: 3min
- Delivery delay: 0s
- Receive message wait time: 1s
- Message retention period: 1d
- Maximum message size: 256Kb

Associated DLQ has Maximum receives of 100

[image: SQS]

The consuming lambda is configured as

- Memory: 128Mb
- Timeout: 10s
- Triggers: The source SQS queue, Batch size: 10, Batch window: None

[image: lambda]

And the actual logic I have in my lambda is quite simple, really. Event it receives is the `Records` in the queue. Lambda might get more than one record at a time but all records are handled separately.

```
console.log('Response', response);

if (response.status === 'CREATED') {

  /* some code here */

  const deleteParams = {
    QueueUrl: queueUrl, /* required */
    ReceiptHandle: receiptHandle /* required */
  };

  console.log('Removing record from ', queueUrl, 'with params', deleteParams);    
  await sqs.deleteMessage(deleteParams).promise();
} else {
  /* any record that ends up here, are never seen again :( */
  console.log('Keeping record in', eventSourceARN);
}
```

What do :( ?!?!11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an AWS Lambda function is triggered from an Amazon SQS queue, all activities related to SQS are handled by the Lambda service. **Your code should not call any Amazon SQS functions.**

The messages will be provided to the AWS Lambda function via the `event` parameter. When the function successfully exits, the Lambda service will delete the messages from the queue.

Your code should not be calling `DeleteMessage()`.

If you wish to signal that *some* of the messages were not successfully processed, you can use a [partial batch response](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-lambda-partial-batch-response-sqs-event-source/) to indicate which messages were successfully processed. The AWS Lambda service will then make the unsuccessful messages available on the queue again.

Answer (score 3):

> otherwise I do nothing with the receiptHandle which I think should then keep the message in the queue

That's [not now it works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html):

> Lambda polls the queue and invokes your Lambda function synchronously with an event that contains queue messages. Lambda reads messages in batches and invokes your function once for each batch. **When your function successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the queue.**

Comment: Please, elaborate

Comment: @MikkoViitala I'm not sure what elaboration you're asking for. What @Parsifal and the docs are telling you is that when an SQS queue triggers a lambda with `n` messages from the queue, the messages enter their visibility timeout, and if the lambda exits successfully the messages are deleted from the queue. If the lambda fails, the messages either become visible again, or, if you have a DLQ, get sent there.

Comment: Yeah the docs. I browsed through them, had case of TL;DR and missed the point that I need an actual return value and not to try handle deletion by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who answered. So I got this "problem" solved just by going through the documents.

I'll provide more detailed answer to my own question here in case someone besides me didn't get it on the first go :)

So function should return `batchItemFailures` object containing message ids of failures.

So, for example, one can have Lambda handler as

```
/**
 * Handler
 *
 * @param {*} event SQS event
 * @returns {Object} batch item failures
 */
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('Starting ' + process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME);
  console.log('Received event', event);

  event = typeof event === 'object'
    ? event
    : JSON.parse(event);

  const batchItemFailures = await execute(event.Records);

  if (batchItemFailures.length > 0) {
    console.log('Failures', batchItemFailures);
  } else {
    console.log('No failures');
  }

  return {
    batchItemFailures: batchItemFailures
  }
}
```

and execute function, that handles the messages

```
/**
 * Execute
 *
 * @param {Array} records SQS records
 * @returns {Promise<*[]>} batch item failures
 */
async function execute (records) {
  let batchItemFailures = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < records.length; index++) {
    const record = records[index];

    // ...some async stuff here

    if (someSuccessCondition) {
      console.log('Life is good');
    } else {
      batchItemFailures.push({
        itemIdentifier: record.messageId
      });
    }
  }

  return batchItemFailures;
}
```